# ListBox instantly deselects when I click it in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

It's inside an updatepanel, as it gets updated in response to another drop down box.

I suspect when I click it, it is posting back or something, which is causing it to de-select. Do you know how I can stop it from doing this, as the selecteditemchanged event is a trigger for another update panel, and when it triggers it errors because selectedindex is -1 (because it deselects instantly when I click it)

Edit: Turning off autopostback fixes it, but then it no longer works as a trigger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by checking for postback and another condition in the updatepanel.